# Is the last release of Ubuntu Touch LTS?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, support

I was wondering if the last release of Ubuntu Touch was a long term support (LTS) version, on behalf of all the people who have bought tablets or phones and want to keep them going.

Comment: The phones and tablets won't die just because Ubuntu Touch is discontinued. They just won't get updates .. which of course can be worrying enough.

Comment: Very true, but without updates it will stagnant and go no where.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu touch will stop receiving updates after June 30, 2017. So, no it is really no LTS in any meaningful way.

This https://ubports.com/ rather than canonical is a last hope for people who believed and invested in the idea, but it remains to be seen if this is a viable project.

All devices running Ubuntu Touch will continue to function as normal after that, but no further updates will be available.

Developers can continue updating their apps and users can continue to download and install updates of applications until the end of 2017.

Comment: do you have a reference for this information? It seems to be very useful and unique on the site.

Comment: @Zanna There was an official canonical statement on the topic at the time. I was unable to find it now. The closest to an official statement I could find now was https://www.networkworld.com/article/3191867/open-source-tools/ubuntu-phone-security-updates-end-in-june-app-store-closing.html